# Woocommerce: Display shipping class in variable products

Tags: wordpress, class, woocommerce

I would like to display the shipping class on the single product page, after choosing a product from variable products. For example: I have a Bike in 3 different colors (red, blue and green):

- Bike red has the shipping class "Free delivery"
- Bike blue has the shipping class "Extra delivery"
- Bike green has the shipping class "Normal Delivery"

Now if I choose a variation (for example the red one) I would like to display "Shipping class: Free delivery"

I achieve that for single products, but not for variations:

```
Shipping Class: <?php echo $product->get_shipping_class(); ?>
```

I added the same code to variable.php, but it is not working. It shows "Shipping class:" but not the class name, if I choose a product.

I am thankful for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
( function($) {
    // capturing even when select option is change
    $('form.cart').on('change', '.variations select', function() {


        //DO some stuff here 

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am not that good in programming. What should i paste in "// DO some stuff here"? Thank you.